# Laravel 5.2 -> 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo um curso de `php/laravel` , o professor usa a versão 5.2 do laravel e eu gostaria de usar a versão 5.6 , no caso os diretórios são diferentes, no 5.2 tem a pasta `layouts` e na versão 5.6 não tem, como posso fazer?

Answer (score -2):

No caso da pasta layout, você pode cria-la manualmente dentro da pasta *views*. No entanto, existem diferenças entre as versões que o seu professor pode demonstrar e na sua atual versão não funcionar.

O que foi depreciado da versão 5.2 para 5.3
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.2-deprecations